# Return multiple results from class with return instead echo?

Tags: php, oop

I am new to PHP OOP.

I want to retreive all results from the db, but not using echo inside the method but RETURN (as I hear often methods shouldn't echo anything but only return), as I am doing in the following:

```
class MySqlDb {

    public $conn;
    public $numRows;

    function __construct($host, $un, $p, $db) {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($host, $un, $p, $db);
    }

    function get_smth() {
        // $conn = new mysqli($host, $un, $p, $db);
        $q = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $r = $this->conn->query($q) or die(mysqli_error());
        $this->numRows = $r->num_rows;
        // return "<p>A total of $this->numRows records were found</p>";
        while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['title'].'<br>';
        }
    }

}

$t = new MySqlDb( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'oop' );
$t->get_smth();
```

I would like to change `echo $row['title'].'<br>';` to `return $row['title'].'<br>';` and still work the same (now I just get the first result if I use return). What needs changing?

Comment: Ask the DB interface to give you all the results in one step, without collecting them manually: [`return $r->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_smth() {
    // $conn = new mysqli($host, $un, $p, $db);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $r = $this->conn->query($q) or die(mysqli_error());
    return  $r->fetch_all();
}
```

then iterate through the result when calling the function:

```
foreach ($t->get_smth() as $array){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `fetch_assoc` only returns one row. Your example will iterate over the *fields* of that row.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP (and most languages), execution of a function stops once it reaches the first `return` statement. In order to return multiple things, you have to return some sort of data structure - the most common is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just load everything into an array and return the array. Keep the output formatting out of this class and leave that up to the whatever is calling this class.

```
$return_array = array();
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return_array[]['title'] =  $row['title'];
}
return $return_array;
```

Comment: OK but where am I supposed to loop thru results? I want to use this to use the method: echo $t->get_smth();

Comment: That `while` loop goes through the results.